# How to remove border bottom width in ant design modal header

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm building web app with Ant Design Vue.

I would like to know how to remove `bottom-width` in the header of `<a-modal>`.

This is the screenshot of what I would like to.

[image]

This is my code.

```
<template>
  <a-modal width="1000px" title="demo">
    Hi, Modal
  </a-modal>
</template>

<script>
:

</script>

<style lang="less" scoped>
.ant-modal-header {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
</style>
```

I know the class `ant-modal-header` defines `border-bottom-width` in Chrome Developer Tool.

So I defined new `ant-modal-header` in `<style lang="less" scoped>` to overwrite design, but somehow, it doesn't work.

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools to determine why your CSS isn't working. Usually there's something with a more specific selector overriding your styles. You just to make your selector _more_ specific

Comment: What happens if you try to overwrite it in not `scoped` style tags `<style lang="less">`? Does it overwrite the design, try adding `!important` to it, does that do anything?

Comment: @JakubASuplicki if anything, using `scoped` would make the rule more specific so I'd recommend leaving that in

Comment: @Phil I just remember myself having an issue with something similar while using one of the `datepickers`. Overwriting the styles inside `scoped` tags simply did not do anything. However, it was working fine without `scoped` tags. I wonder what could be the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrapClassName` prop to give class to this specific modal container, and once you give class name to container you can target it but scoped style won't work here because classes are assigned in your current component

so something like this should work.

```html
<template>
  <a-modal width="1000px" wrap-class-name="my-special-modal" title="demo">
    Hi, Modal
  </a-modal>
</template>

<script>
:

</script>

<style lang="less">
.my-special-modal {
  .ant-modal-header {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to know how to apply style without removing scoped in style tag.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.ant-modal-header {
  border-top: 0 none;
}
```